# Expreso Store - Don't show modifier price if zero

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

We're using Store 2.5.0 and EE 2.9.2.  On the checkout page we're showing the value of any modifiers using:

```
{if price_mod_val}({price_mod}){/if}
```

It's returning the value of the modifiers ok, but it's also displaying +0.00 if the modifier is empty.

Is there a way to not show the modifier value if it's 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

```
{if price_mod_val && price_mod_val != "+0.00"}({price_mod}){/if}
```

Comment: Heeeey... this person is saying it's displaying "+0.00" .. perhaps update your answer to accommodate that? I don't want to steal it from you :p

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  {if price_mod_val && price_mod_val != "+0.00"}({price_mod}){/if} worked.

Comment: I was assuming price_mod_val would be 0 and price_mod +0.00 because of the explanation. Thank you jrothafer for the replenishment. And you're welcome Baradat, Glad I could help.